# I'm having trouble with the insert function for my binary search tree

Tags: c, search, insert, tree

Basically what's happening in my insert function is that the portion that triggers placing a node to the right of the root in my bst causes the program to crash and I have no idea why. The insert function is as follows.

```
node* insert(node *root, node *element)
{

    // Inserting into an empty tree.
    if (root == NULL)
        return element;
    else {

        // element should be inserted to the right.
        if (element->bk->key < root->bk->key) {

            printf("Inserting in left position.\n");
            // There is a right subtree to insert the node.
            if (root->left != NULL)
                root->left = insert(root->left, element);

            // Place the node directly to the right of root.
            else
                root->left = element;
        }

        // element should be inserted to the left.
        else {

            // There is a left subtree to insert the node.
            if (root->right != NULL)
                root->right = insert(root->right, element);

            // Place the node directly to the left of root.
            else
                root->right = element;
        }

        // Return the root pointer of the updated tree.
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you fix your code indentation.

Comment: Have you tried running this in the debugger?  That would tell you what line it crashed on, and why.

Comment: Show us how you initialize `element` before you call this function.

Answer (score 1):

Best candidate for crash would be

```
if (element->bk->key < root->bk->key)
```

So either `element->bk` or `root->bk` are `NULL` or point to nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's too little information in the question to be sure, so we have to guess. I think the most likely culprit is that `element` might not be initialized correctly. This could mean any of the following:

1. `element` isn't pointing to a valid instance of `node` (uninitialized pointer, dangling pointer etc).
2. `element->bk` is NULL or isn't a valid pointer.
3. `element->left` isn't NULL when the function is entered.
4. `element->right` isn't NULL when the function is entered.

By the way, the function is a lot more complex than it needs to be:

```
node* insert(node *root, node *element) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return element; // Inserting into an empty tree.
    else {
        if (element->bk->key < root->bk->key) {
            printf("Inserting in left position.\n");
            root->left = insert(root->left, element);
        } else {
            printf("Inserting in right position.\n");
            root->right = insert(root->right, element);
        }
        // Return the root pointer of the updated tree.
        return root;
    }
}
```

Notice how the two `if (root->X != NULL)` statements and the two `else` clauses are unnecessary. Calling the function with `root==NULL` will do the right thing, thanks to the `if (root==NULL)` check at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging steps I would take:

1. run in a debugger
2. failing that, print everything before you use it using fflush(stdout) between them so that if you don't get a print you know that that is the piece that is initialized poorly.
3. I would fix your comments so that they actually reflect what you are doing (right and left are backwards in your comments) just so that when you get tired/frustrated you don't confuse yourself.
4. Like aix said simplify, that may solve your issues(although likely not), or at least make it a bit simpler to step through in the debugger, think about, and read.

As has been mentioned if you give us calling/initializing we can help more.